# Android WebView Model loads white page when I click link on first webpage that takes me to second page. second page contains html, css, javascript

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, webview, android-fragmentactivity

Jenna here, I've looked for the past month all over and still can't find answer to this. I've looked through ever question here on stack overflow. if anyone can please help. I honestly can't find a way to upload my sample project, its really small, if anyone has way please let me know or I can also just directly send it to you.

First off I want to say I was able to get this accomplished before using default fragment created by android studio but when I create a custom fragment I have no luck and this was 6 months ago. for some reason its not working either way now. I have a navigation drawer view activity.On the first fragment HomeFragment I have a button, when you click it, it will navigate you to a custom created WebViewFragement. The webview loads up perfectly however when I click a link that takes me to a page that seems to be loading css, java, html, the page takes me to white screen only. I've tried many ways to implement this webview for the past few weeks, so now im asking if anyone here can help. When the fragment loads it loads up https://dominos.com (I've also tried using the https://www.dominos.com. when I click any of the buttons/links with the red arrows, the webview loads up white page. when I click the button with the green arrow it loads up that page because it doesn't have such complicated html/css..etc. (at least I think thats what the difference is. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0v3e.jpg) the page that is suppose to load up when you click any of the buttons that red arrows are pointing to is this page (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPjYq.png)

when I click any of the buttons/links with the red arrows, the webview loads up white page. when I click the button with the green arrow it loads up that page because it doesn't have such complicated html/css..etc. (at least I think thats what the difference is.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0v3e.jpg)

the page that is suppose to load up when you click any of the buttons that red arrows are pointing to is this page

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPjYq.png)

Here is code for my first fragment called HomeFragment

```
package com.dominospizza.couponsgames.ui.home

import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.navigation.findNavController

import com.dominospizza.couponsgames.R
import com.dominospizza.couponsgames.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding



class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var myWebView: WebView

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        val homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)

        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        val root: View = binding.root

        val textView: TextView = binding.textHome
        homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            textView.text = it
        }

        binding.button.setOnClickListener { view ->
            view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_nav_home_to_webViewFragment)


        }
        return root
    }



    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

here is code for my custom WebViewFragment

```
package com.dominospizza.gamescoupons


import android.net.http.SslError
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler
import android.webkit.WebSettings
import android.webkit.WebView
import android.webkit.WebViewClient
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.dominospizza.couponsgames.R
import com.dominospizza.couponsgames.databinding.FragmentWebViewBinding
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest


class WebViewFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentWebViewBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentWebViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        val myWebView: WebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView)


        // Enable debugging of web contents
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        }

        // Set WebViewClient and WebChromeClient
        myWebView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        myWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
                view: WebView?,
                request: WebResourceRequest?
            ): Boolean {
                myWebView.loadUrl(request?.url.toString())
                return true
            }

            override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
                var message = "SSL Certificate error."
                when (error.primaryError) {
                    SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED ->
                        message = "The certificate authority is not trusted."
                    SslError.SSL_EXPIRED ->
                        message = "The certificate has expired."
                    SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH ->
                        message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch."
                    SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID ->
                        message = "The certificate is not yet valid."
                }
                message += "\"SSL Certificate Error\" Do you want to continue anyway?"
                //Log your message
                handler.proceed()
            }
        }

        val userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"

        val webSetting: WebSettings = myWebView.settings
        webSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webSetting.allowContentAccess = true
        webSetting.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW
        webSetting.domStorageEnabled = true
        webSetting.useWideViewPort = true
        webSetting.allowFileAccess = true
        webSetting.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
        webSetting.userAgentString = userAgent

        myWebView.isScrollbarFadingEnabled = false
        myWebView.setInitialScale(1)
        myWebView.settings.loadsImagesAutomatically = true
        myWebView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true

        myWebView.settings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT
        myWebView.settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true)
        myWebView.settings.setSupportZoom(true)
        myWebView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
        myWebView.webViewClient = WebViewClient()

        myWebView.clearCache(true)
        myWebView.clearHistory()



        myWebView.clearCache(true)
        myWebView.clearHistory()


        myWebView.loadUrl("https://dominos.com")

        myWebView.setOnKeyListener(View.OnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
                myWebView.goBack()
                return@OnKeyListener true
            }
            false
        })

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
     }

    }
```

here is version of android studio if that helps.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJX7g.png)

Build gradle for app

```
`plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
namespace 'com.dominospizza.couponsgames'
compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.dominospizza.couponsgames"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

Build gradle for project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.0' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.0' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

here is the logcat

2023-04-23 02:19:02.728  3891-3891  HwViewRootImpl          com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
2023-04-23 02:19:02.730  3891-3891  AudioManager            com.dominospizza.couponsgames        V  querySoundEffectsEnabled...
2023-04-23 02:19:02.756  3891-3891  SysUtils                com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  hw theme is enabled(false)
2023-04-23 02:19:02.756  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  selectHandleChangeEnbled(false), EMUI_Version: 27
2023-04-23 02:19:02.760  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:aw_contents.cc(716)] JNI_AwContents_Init.
2023-04-23 02:19:02.764  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  getEffectiveBackgroundColor forceDarkMode mUseHwDarkMode = true
2023-04-23 02:19:02.765  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  getAdBlockEnabled:false this = org.chromium.android_webview.AwSettings@3739cbe
2023-04-23 02:19:02.783  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  getEffectiveBackgroundColor forceDarkMode mUseHwDarkMode = true
2023-04-23 02:19:02.786  3891-3891  chatty                  com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  uid=10154(com.dominospizza.couponsgames) identical 7 lines
2023-04-23 02:19:02.791  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  getEffectiveBackgroundColor forceDarkMode mUseHwDarkMode = true
2023-04-23 02:19:02.791  3891-3891  AwSettings              com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  getAdBlockEnabled:false this = org.chromium.android_webview.AwSettings@3739cbe
2023-04-23 02:19:02.950  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:navigation_request.cc(2192)] [AdBlock] Redirect to https//***, try to get adblock switch from UI.
2023-04-23 02:19:03.088  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:navigation_request.cc(2192)] [AdBlock] Redirect to https//***, try to get adblock switch from UI.
2023-04-23 02:19:03.757  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:03.758  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:08.842  3891-3891  HwViewRootImpl          com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  removeInvalidNode all the node in jank list is out of time
2023-04-23 02:19:10.801  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:10.802  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:11.078  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:11.078  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:11.520  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:gesture_detector.cc(630)] Stop drag long press timer.
2023-04-23 02:19:11.573  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:11.574  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:11.606  3891-3891  InputMethodManager      com.dominospizza.couponsgames        W  startInputReason = 4
2023-04-23 02:19:11.608  3891-3891  HwRemoteIn...hodManager com.dominospizza.couponsgames        W  isCasting false because IHwDistributedWindowManager is invalid.
2023-04-23 02:19:11.893  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:11.893  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:11.912  3891-4167  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:network_service_network_delegate.cc(161)] INFO: resource : https//*** error code: 400
2023-04-23 02:19:11.928  3891-4167  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:network_service_network_delegate.cc(246)] final url https//*** error_code -3 ip address: ignored
2023-04-23 02:19:11.931  3891-4167  chatty                  com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  uid=10154(com.dominospizza.couponsgames) NetworkService identical 2 lines
2023-04-23 02:19:11.932  3891-4167  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:network_service_network_delegate.cc(246)] final url https//*** error_code -3 ip address: ignored
2023-04-23 02:19:11.940  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(27)] enter ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout
2023-04-23 02:19:11.940  3891-3891  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        I  [INFO:adaptive_relayout_impl.cc(37)] exit ShouldDoAdaptiveRelayout, should[0]
2023-04-23 02:19:12.048  3891-4167  hwschromium-3355        com.dominospizza.couponsgames        W  [WARNING:spdy_session.cc(3391)] Received HEADERS for invalid stream 5

Comment: One thing I seen in the Logcat is there is an ad blocker.. if you have an ad blocker on your browser this could be preventing the page from loading correctly. I have ran into this issue before

Comment: Thanks @Camp Nerd, thats weird that it mentions adblocker, as I started with the default template from android studio and only added a button and a webview, no type of adblocker of such, but thanks for pointing that out. I'll research now to see if that is something enabled. I'll update post if I find that to be the case.

Comment: from the research I;ve done so far, it doesnt look like kotlin's webview has adblocker enabled by default. still wierd why thats showing up in my logcat. I just created another project from scratch and I get the same logcat. hmm..

Comment: this keeps popping my in logcat when I click back after I get the white page, and click the dominos website link that takes me back to the white page. But im not finding anything about it on the internet. "hwschromium-3355 com.dominospizza.couponsgames I [INFO:network_service_network_delegate.cc(161)] INFO: resource : https//*** error code: 400 2023-04-23 02:19:11.928 3891-4167.

Comment: Like the website works, no issue with loading the webpage in a regular browser. it's even loading in my fragment app that I created 6 months ago. its just not working with this new version of android studio, im not sure if the new version has some kind of different configs I need to do.

Comment: I will do some testing today. I am fixing to be building a web browser app to push out to my Google Play Account for download with my other apps. I will do some testing as well.. I am using the newest version of Flamingo.. (which I hate very much). So I will let you know a little later today the results. Now I use a physical phone I don't use emulator. Have you tested it on a physical phone or just the emulator?

Comment: I just realized something.. JavaScript is by default false. Add this to the WebView and see if it works.....  getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)

Comment: Supporting JavaScript: JavaScript is by default turned off in WebView widgets. Hence web pages containing javascript references won’t work properly. To enable java script the following snippet needs to be called on the webview instance:

Comment: Thanks for checking it out. yeah I hate the new version as well. Yes I have set javascript enabled, here is my code " webSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true"